# Adjustment of Door closer screws for holding door in fully open position

Tags: doors

Door closer in attached/linked photo controls both opening and closing of door but
My door closer is not allowing/holding(stand still) the door in fully open position since last week(it was actually working fine before that and it holded door in fully open position)

I want that my door remains in fully open position unless i close the door when i go inside

Which of the screws shown in photo i need to tune and how
[image]

Comment: is it supposed to hold the door open?

Comment: As noted in the answers, That is not designed to hold the door open. It is to designed to close the door.

Comment: @AlaskaMan, i did not read the answers ... i asked the first thing that popped in my mind

Comment: It is supposed to do both opening and closing

Answer (score 1):

I've installed that brand/model of door closer before, and it doesn't have a hold open function as far as I know.

You'll want a floor stop, or get a different door closer that has a hold open function.

Comment: +1. Not all closers are equipped with a Hold Open Arm, and this looks like one without it. Usually, they work by friction. Opening the door to a certain degree tightens a nut which causes the arm to stick at a point, holding the door open.

Answer (score 0):

The door closer may not be adjusted long enough to allow reaching the fully open position, that is the threaded section on the arm.

Then you may have to adjust the closing rate as well, there are usually two screws for this, but only turn a fraction of a turn 1/8 or 1/16 or even less - tends to have a large effect...